# Integrate Mailchimp into Laravel with API

Tags: php, laravel, mailchimp

I am new to Laravel and am stuck.  I've use the [Hugo Firth](https://github.com/hugofirth/laravel-mailchimp) api wrapper in Laravel for mailchimp.  What I can't figure out is where to put this the code in laravel.  Does it go on the controller?  This is the code for subscribe:

```
MailChimpWrapper::lists()->subscribe($list_id, array('email' => $email_address));
```

I also need the list_id..do I put the list ID there or create a variable called $list_id = with my list id? or can I put it right on my landing page?

```
@section('content')
{{ MailChimpWrapper::lists()->subscribe($list_id, array('email' => $email_address)); }}
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-9">
```

EDIT

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('landing/landing');
    MailChimpWrapper::lists()->subscribe('list_id', array('email' => $email_address));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to find the list ID in MailChimp. It's more of a static thing, than a variable. I only use 1 list, so it's actually just coded as a string for me.

And it goes in your controller, so this is what I have:

```
MailchimpWrapper::lists()->subscribe('list_id', ['email' => $email], [
    'FNAME' => $firstname,
    'LNAME' => $lastname
]);
```

Comment: Would it go in my controller like so?  See edit above

Comment: Well, it depends. I have it in a controller with no View. That is literally the only thing in my controller. You could have it in your controller like that, except it has to be above the return View:: line